# Hibernate remove just the relation, not the entity on the relation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a one to many relation on post class, and on the relation table I have one to one relation with user. Everything works find, but i want to be able to remove the relation, keeping the user entity, is that possible?

At this moment with the annotation `orphanRemoval = true` when I remove from post Detail list an element, this its removed from post_details table but the user is removed too.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "ta_post")    
    public class Post{
       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
       private int id;
       private Date fcDate;
       @OneToMany(mappedBy="post", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
       private List<PostDetails>;
    }
```

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "ta_user") 
    public class User{
       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
       private int id;
       private int mail;
    }
```

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "ta_post_details") 
    public class PostDetails{
       private int id;
       @ManyToOne
       @JoinColumn(name="post_id")    
       private Post post;
       @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
       @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
       private User user;
       private String postComments;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must remove the CascadeType.ALL from the PostDetails. If you want to be able to change the User through the PostDetails, you can set the CascadeType to PERSIST or MERGE. If you want to create a PostDetail along with an User, you need to include the CascadeType CREATE.
I'd guess you are creating the user somewhere else and you just associate one with a Post, so removing the CascadeType.ALL should be enough to not delete your User from the database.

Comment: and I should keep the ```orphanRemoval = true``` annotation?

Comment: No you don't need to. You will remove only the PostDetails (I assume there's no need to keep it in your database because there's no association to a user anymore)

Comment: Sorry, just to recall: the orphanRemoval should be kept in the Post class. In the PostDetails, you should remove the CascadeType.ALL and don't put orphanRemoval. If you leave the orphanRemoval in the Post class, it will remove the PostDetails from the database in case the association is removed. If you don't leave it, you might have a lot of invalid data into the associated table, which might require a further cleanup because they will be useless.